Function to extract to a temporary directory
In my code I use something like this multiple times:
with tempfile.TemporaryDirectory() as tmpdir:

    retm = extract_subpath(path1, tmpdir)
    if retm["returncode"] != 0:
        raise RuntimeError("Failed to extract file: {}".format(retm["stderr"].strip()))

    file = check_valid(tmpdir)

    ret = extract_subpath(path2, tmpdir)
    if ret["returncode"] != 0:
        raise RuntimeError("Failed to extract file: {}".format(ret["stderr"].strip()))

    validate(tmpdir)

Here both path1 and path2 are extracted in the same temporary directory.
I want to convert this to a common function. What would be the best way to do that?
With something like this if I need to use the same tmpdir multiple times like above I cannot because each invocation will return a different temporary directory.
def extract_tmpdir(path: str) -> str:
    with tempfile.TemporaryDirectory() as tmpdir:
        ret = extract_subpath(path, tmpdir)

        if ret["returncode"] != 0:
          raise RuntimeError("Failed to extract file: {}".format(ret["stderr"].strip()))

        return tmpdir


You don't have to use the context manager with tempfile.TemporaryDirectory(). You could just save a reference with tmpdir  = tempfile.TemporaryDirectory() and use it wherever you see fit. You could even wrap the in a class, create the temp directory in the __init__ method and give the class an extract_subpath() that uses the directory.

I'm choosing to interpret your question as "How can I extract this function without creating a bunch of copies of tmpdir?" rather than "What is the best way to do this?" since the latter seems opinion-based.
If you don't want to make copies of tmpdir, you can always just pass it in as a parameter to your extraction method:
def extract_tmpdir(path: str, tmpdir: tempfile.TemporaryDirectory):
    ret = extract_subpath(path, tmpdir)
    if ret["returncode"] != 0:
        raise RuntimeError("Failed to extract file: {}".format(ret["stderr"].strip()))
    return ret

Then, you can create tmpdir once and pass it every time you call the function:
with tempfile.TemporaryDirectory() as tmpdir:
    retm = extract_tmpdir(path1, tmpdir)
    file = check_valid(tmpdir)
    ret = extract_tmpdir(path2, tmpdir)
    validate(tmpdir)

